# How to send new password from Magento CSV import of Customers

Tags: php, email, magento, csv-import

We have been trying to modify the Customer.php file ( import/export ) to get it to send out the new account details automatically as it imports the customers from a CSV file.

We are working in the right area as we dropped a simple mail() call which was called (we received the emails) for every new row. The problem arises when trying to get it to generate a new random password and send out the new account details - it never sends any mail and we cannot figure out why! Code follows ( Edited from app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer.php )

```
 /**
 * Update and insert data in entity table.
 *
 * @param array $entityRowsIn Row for insert
 * @param array $entityRowsUp Row for update
 * @return Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Customer
 */
protected function _saveCustomerEntity(array $entityRowsIn, array $entityRowsUp)
{
    if ($entityRowsIn) {
        $this->_connection->insertMultiple($this->_entityTable, $entityRowsIn);

          // BEGIN: Send New Account Email          
          $cust = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
          $cust->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());              
          foreach($entityRowsIn as $idx => $u){
            // Failed
            $cust->loadByEmail($u['email']);
            $cust->setConfirmation(NULL);
            $cust->setPassword($cust->generatePassword(8));
            $cust->save();
            $cust->sendNewAccountEmail();
            //$cust->sendPasswordReminderEmail(); // this call doesnt work either
          }
          // END: Send New Account Email

    }
    if ($entityRowsUp) {
        $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate(
            $this->_entityTable,
            $entityRowsUp,
            array('group_id', 'store_id', 'updated_at', 'created_at')
        );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder to improve performance magento 'caches' object, so when trying to load an object in a loop you either need to load a new instance or call it reset() method

```
$website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();       
foreach($entityRowsIn as $idx => $u){
    $cust = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $cust->setWebsiteId($website_id);
    $cust->loadByEmail($u['email']);
    $cust->setPassword($cust->generatePassword(8));
    $cust->save();
    $cust->sendNewAccountEmail();  // if you are getting 2 email then remove this line
}
```

If you are load a large number of customers then you may run in to memory issues and my need to look a other technique using `reset()`

If this code is being run from the Administration section of Magento then you will need to make sure that you set the correct Website ID (  `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()` will return the incorrect one ).

From the front end this code will work fine but for Admin work you should use '1' or whatever your Front end websites ID is as the getId() method was returning '0' in the Admin area! Small gotcha but had me going for hours!

Comment: agree with this answer; you can't use `loadByEmail` unless you specify the website before

Comment: This solution still does not send out any emails :( Good heads up on the object caching though!

Comment: Just to clarify - the import still goes ahead successfully though - its just not sending out the 'New Account' emails to ANY of the people in the CSV.

The current CSV only has five test accounts to import and we are making sure that they being imported by clearing the entire customer list to begin with before trying the import each time.

Comment: If you go to the Admin -> customer and edit one a customer (send new pasword check) with a email in your csv file, do you get the email?

Comment: Yes we do - just confirmed by editing my own name and checking the 'New Generated Password' box, received the email a few seconds later.

Comment: BTW - when I first started trying to do this I added a simple @mail() call - this emailed me correctly, with the expected email address for the account as the msg and the correct index number in the subject line - so it deffo loops over the $entityRowsIn array .. its the Magento emails that are refusing to send out programatically

Comment: I just tested the code above on magento v1.7 (without the loop) and it does work. Copy the code without the loop to template/catalog/product/list.phtml and hard code a email address. then go to a category list page on your website and see if you get an email.

Comment: Popped the code into the list.phtml and hit refresh and yes, received the email ( Magento 1.7.0.2 ) - so how come it wont send while inside the import process?

Comment: Debug it by do a print_r($u['email']) and print_r($cust->getData()) in the loop

Comment: I know that $u['email'] was correct because I got that value in my simple mail() test email. Tried dumping data inside the loop earlier - all I get is the return "import success" page

Comment: Where are you running this script from? It could be that your running this script within the admin or a different store scope so Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() is not the same as the frontend website id. To test if this is the case do the same test in 'list.phtml' and create a fake $entityRowsIn array with two emails

Comment: I edited the app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer.php - its the admin function which allows the import of CSV files .... sooooo .... its giving me the incorrect websiteId if i run from Admin yes?

Comment: You tell me... do a `die($website_id);` in 'list.phtml' and in your admin code are id the same? Also in you customer admin are you having duplicate customer records

Comment: Yeah - In Front End WebID is 1, in Admin WebID is 0. I Hardcoded the ID as '1' in the Customer.php file and it worked! Thank you for your Help!

Comment: Just an update - the code handled the creation of over 3000 accounts with ease - most useful Magento hack I have ever done - thanks @R.S

Answer (score 0):

I had found this script on how to Auto generate password for existing customers

```
$passwordLength = 10;
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach ($customers as $customer){
    $customer->setPassword($customer->generatePassword($passwordLength))->save();
    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
}
```

Comment: Thats Cool - but we needed a solution that both created accounts from an imported csv file AND sent out their new generated credentials. If you would like me to pop the code up for an example then drop a comment - it as the chap above that helped as the problem was that I was using an incorrect Site ID number while importing - hardcoding it to the correct one cleared my issue!